# Where store an API Token for Jenkins used in Dockerfile

Tags: security, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I need to retrieve an Artifact from my Jenkins to setup a Docker-Image.

My Jenkins needs an authentication which can be passed with wget via

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=user --http-password=apiToken --secure-protocol=TLSv1 http://jenkins.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/build?token=TOKEN
```

as seen [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients)

Now I need to pass the api token to my Dockerfile.

As far as the Dockerfile is public accessible I don't want to store the api-token plaintext within the file.
An alternative will be a Docker [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) but they do not recommend it for Passwords or security relevant data as it can be seen with "docker history"

Copying and deleting a file containing the password seems not so elegant to me.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to download the artefact before doing `docker build` and then using `COPY artefact /somewhere` inside your `Dockerfile`.

Since you are worried about the size implications of this, one could use `--squash` during build to compress the layers.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/

If you wish to play with multi-stage builds (experimental), you could also use:

```
FROM base_image AS prepare

COPY artefact /something
RUN chown user /something

FROM base_image

COPY --from=prepare /something /something
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

Comment: This was my first attempt. The Problem is, that COPY copies the artefact as ROOT and I need to run the app as another user. Performing chown inside the Dockerfile increases the Image Size dramatically because of the  additional layer created (Artefact Size ~1G).

Comment: You could use the `--squash` option during build, which would solve your image size problem.